# Change Nested State Value With A Single Function? (javascript/React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, state

I have some react user privilege state data I need to manage. I would like the ability to change the object privileges based on their property through a dynamic function. I'm not sure how to target the specific nested privilege property to change the value. Is this possible?

Question: How can I change the value of a nested privilege property to the functions type and value parameter?

Heres an Example:

```js
const [userPrivilages, setUserPrivilages] = useState([{
    _id: "123"
    privilages: {
      edit: true, //before!
      share: true,
      del: false
    }
  },
  {
    ...more users
  }
])

//my attempt

const changePrivilage = (type, value) => {
    const newPrivilages = userPrivilages.map(user => {
        return {
          ...user,
          privilages: {
            ...privilages,
            //change the privilage of "type" from the functions parameter to the value parameter
          }
        }) setUserPrivilages(newPrivilages)
    }

    changePrivilage("edit", false)
```

Desired output:

```js
const [userPrivilages, setUserPrivilages] = useState([{
    _id: "123"
    privilages: {
      edit: false, //After!
      share: true,
      del: false
    }
  },
  {
    ...more users
  }
])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` to refer to variable as a key like below:

```
const changePrivilage = (type, value) => {
    const newPrivilages = userPrivilages.map(user => {
        return {
          ...user,
          privilages: {
            ...user.privilages,
            [type]: value // here it is !!!
          }
        }) setUserPrivilages(newPrivilages)
    }
```

Comment: I think `...privilages,` should be `...user.privilages,`

Comment: @thelonglqd This worked perfectly in my actual code! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :
(see comments for understanding code)

```
const changePrivilage = (type,value) => {
    const newUserPrivilages = userPrivilages.map(user => { 
        let newPrivilages = user.privilages; // get old privilages of user
        newPrivilages[type] = value; // update type with new value
        return {
            ...user,
            privilages: newPrivilages, // set privilages as newPrivilages
        };
    });
    setUserPrivilages(newUserPrivilages);
};
```

Note : this will change properties for all users. If you want to update only for specific user, pass `_id` as well to `changePrivilage` and execute `newPrivilages[type] = value; // update type with new value` inside `if` condition comparing user `_id`.